# Should agents only hold immutable values

Tags: concurrency, clojure

In Clojure Programming (OReilly) there is an example where both a java.io.BufferedWriter, and a java.io.Printwriter is put inside an agent (one agent for each). These are then written to inside the agent action. The book says that it is safe to perform io in an agent action. As I understand it all side effecting operations are ok inside an agent action. This is because agent actions inside commits are only run if the commit is succesful. And agent actions inside other agent actions are only run after the outer agent action completes successfully. Agent actions in general are guaranteed to be applied serially.

The Clojure [documentation](http://clojure.org/agents) says this: "The state of an Agent should be itself immutable...".

As I understand it, the reason that atoms and refs must hold immutable values is so that clojure can roll back and retry commits several times.

What I don't understand is:

1: If Clojure makes sure that agent actions are only run once, why must agent values be immutable.
(for example if I hold a java array in an agent, and add to it in an agent action, this should be fine because the action will only run once. This is very similar to adding lines to a BufferedWriter)

2: Is java.io.BufferedWriter considered immutable? I understand that you could have a stable reference to one, but if the agent action is performing io on it, should it still be considered immutable?

3: If BufferedWriter is considered immutable, how do I decide if other similar java classes are immutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As I see it:**

Values held by agents should be 'effectively immutable' (term borrowed from JCIP), in that they should always be conceptually equal to themselves.

This means, if I `.clone()` an object and compare both copies, `original.equals(copy)` should be true, no matter of what I do (and when).

In this sense, an instance of the typical `Employee` class full of getters/setters can not be guaranteed to equal to itself, in face of mutability: `equals()` will be defined as a field-by-field comparison, so the test can fail.

A BufferedWriter though, does not represent a value - its equality is defined in terms of being exactly the same object in memory. So it has a 'sound' mutability -unlike Employee's- which makes it apt for wrapping it in an agent.

I believe that you are right in that from the STM point of view, agent-value mutability wouldn't hurt a lot. But it would in that it'd break Clojure's time model, in which you 'cannot change the past', etc.

On deciding whether a Java class is immutable: impossible without diving into the implementation. You don't have to care about this too much though.

I'd make the following taxonomy of types in Java-land:

- Mutable objects which (badly) represent values - `Employee`, etc. *Never wrap them in a Clojure reference type.*
- Immutable objects which represent values - their immutability is reflected in the doc, or in naming conventions ("EmployeeBuilder"). *Safe to wrap in any Clojure reference.*
- Unmanaged collection types - ArrayList, etc. *Avoid except for interop purposes.*
- Managed reference/collection types - AtomicReference, blocking queues... *They play fine with Clojure, dubious to wrap them in Clojure references though.*
- 'IO' types - BufferedWriter, Swing stuff... you don't care about their mutability because they don't represent values at all - you just want them for their side effects. *It might make sense to guard them in agents to guarantee access serialization.*

Answer (score 2):

The agent value should be immutable because someone can do this:

```
 (def my-agent (agent (BufferedWriter.)))
 (.write @my-agent "Hello world")
```

Which is basically modifying the agent value (in this case the writer) without going through agent control mechanism.

Yes, `BufferedWriter` is mutable because by writing to it you can change its internal state. It is like a pointer or reference and not a `value.`

Comment: Nobody uses BufferedWriter as reference or collection type though - mutating them is closer to being a side effect than to representing change in a program.

Comment: BufferedWriter can write to any underlying stream, it can be even be memory stream hence it can be state

Comment: I guess yes, strictly speaking :) I find very important anyway: 1) to distinguish between kinds of mutability, and 2) that Clojure, being a dynamically typed language, delegates certain responsabilities to the programmer. Not writing code like `(.write @my-agent "Hello world")` (in the general case) is one of them.